# How ruthless is Geralt of Rivia?

Tags: the-witcher

In the scene *The Butcher of Blaviken*, Geralt killed or gravely wounded half a dozen men without hesitating but when fighting Renfri, he is rather hesitant and even though he had warned her "If we cross swords...", impling he'll kill her if they do cross swords.

In the trailer for *The Witcher 3: Wild Hunt*, he kills three men he considers evil, again without hesitation, even torturing one by hanging him and deliver him at the merci of his victim.

He protects Duny at the court of Cintra as he's an intelligent being (and not a monster) and also wants to help the Hirikka (before it is slayed for Kingdom and Honor). It somehow just is not consistent for me that at one moment, he kills without any hesitation and at others, he tries to save lifes and is risking his own. Is there a code he follows what intelligent being it is fine to slay and who shall be protected? And how ruthlessly is Geralt following that if he determines somebody needs to be killed? With *Butcher of Blaviken*, it would seem that he doesn't have any hesitation about killing people in his way.

Comment: Note that the Witcher Netflix show and the video game are two separate continuities and thus the Geralt in each of them is not the same person and would not necessarily behave the same way.

Comment: He kills when he believes that he is protecting the weak: Renfri's henchmen were just common bandits happy to slaughter the village, but he believed that she could be saved, hence he hesitated. In the game trailer he simply couldn't stand when he saw three men going to torture and murder a woman (innocent or not). In D'n'D standards, he would be Neutral Good :)

Comment: It is a bit clearer in the books than the series - the fight takes place near a public market where Renfri and the bandits are about to kill civilians until Stregobor comes out of his tower (which he won't). The short story is about picking "the lesser evil", in this case killing the bandits before they start a massacre.